# Mocking and Marshal.ReleaseComObject()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a problem setting up a mock, so I can call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` on my Mocked object.

I am using Moq to set up a mock of a type IFeature (from a third-party interface library). The mock setup is fairly simple:

```
  var featureMock = new Mock<IFeature>(); 
  IFeature feature = featureMock.Object;
```

In my code, The feature object is created in a while loop, running through a type of cursor (`FeatureCursor`). Due to legacy issues of the third-party library, the `Feature` object has known problems with memory leakage. Thus, I have to release the objects through `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, like shown in the code;

```
public class XXX
{

      public void DoThis()
      {
        IFeatureCursor featureCursor; 
        //...fill the cursor with features; 

        IFeature feature = null; 
        while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature)!= null)
        {
           //Do my stuff with the feature
          Marshal.ReleaseComObject(feature); 
        }

      }

}
```

It works when I use real a featurecursor and features, but when when I mock the feature in a unittest, I get an error:

```
"System.ArgumentException : The object's type must be __ComObject or derived from __ComObject."
```

But how do I apply this to my Mock object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mocked `IFeature` will just be a standard .NET class, not a `COM` object which is why your test is currently throwing the `The object's type must be __ComObject...` exception.

You just need to wrap the call to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(feature);` and check whether the object is a COM object first:

```
if (Marshal.IsComObject(feature)
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(feature);
}
```

Then your test will work pass but won't call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` (the production code will call it).

Since it sounds like you actually want to verify somehow that `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` was called by the code you will need to do a little more work.

Since it's a static method and doesn't actually do anything to the object itself the only option you have is to create a wrapper:

```
public interface IMarshal
{
    void ReleaseComObject(object obj);
}

public class MarshalWrapper : IMarshal
{
    public void ReleaseComObject(object obj)
    {
        if (Marshal.IsComObject(obj))
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Then make your code depend on `IMarshal` which you can also mock in your test and verify:

```
public void FeaturesAreReleasedCorrectly()
{
    var mockFeature = new Mock<IFeature>();
    var mockMarshal = new Mock<IMarshal>();

    // code which calls IFeature and IMarshal
    var thing = new Thing(mockFeature.Object, mockMarshal.Object);
    thing.DoThis();

    // Verify that the correct number of features were released
    mockMarshal.Verify(x => x.ReleaseComObject(It.IsAny<IFeature>()), Times.Exactly(5));
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!! Thank you very much. Why didn't I think about making a MarshalWrapper. I wrap just about everything else in my code :-)